# TV Show about invading aliens with two fingers fused together

Tags: story-identification, tv, alien-invasion

I remember being told about an old science fiction television series about an alien invasion. In the series the only way to identify an alien from a human was that two of their fingers would appear to be fused together. I have never been able to identify what series this is from. I'm pretty sure I heard about this sometime within a few years of 1990. I had the impression at the time that this show was probably on sometime during the 70's or early 80's, but I'm not at all sure. Has anyone ever heard of this story?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be [The Invaders](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Invaders) TV show from the late sixties. 
The aliens could often be detected by a weirdly angled finger which sounds like what you might be thinking of with the fused fingers. As described on Wikipedia:

> "Most of the aliens, in particular the lowest-ranking members or
>   workers in green jumpsuits, were emotionless and had deformed little
>   fingers which could not move and were bent at an unnatural angle,
>   although there were "deluxe models" who could manipulate this finger."

It was re shown on BBC 2 in the UK in 90s which may explain why you heard about it then.

Comment: Interesting. I think this might be what I heard about. I could have remembered the thing about the fingers wrong, or the person telling me about it could have misspoken. But yeah, I think this might be it. Thanks.

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CHf1PxkVEAEUi1N.jpg

Comment: “deluxe models” — I'm guessing this is to explain the early episodes before the writers thought up the pinky thing.

Comment: I always thought the punk band 'Stiff Little Fingers' took it's name from that show, however  Google tells me otherwise.....aw well